# Function in Javascript that returns closest distance of two given array indices

Tags: javascript

I want to write a function with for-loops that finds the index of the number 1 in an array and returns the difference to the index of the number 2 that is closest to number 1 (number 1 only appears once). For instance:

```
Input: [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]
Output: 4

Input: [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0 ,2]
Output: 1
```

My try

```
function closest (array) {

  let elem=array.findIndex(index=>index === 1)
  let numberplus=0;
  let numberminus=0;


  for (let i=elem; i<array.length; i++){
    if (array[elem+1] === 2)
    {numberplus+=array[elem+1]-elem;}
    break;    
    }

  for (let i=elem; i>=0; i--) {
    if (array[elem-1] ===2)
    {numberminus+=array[elem-1]-elem;}
    break;
    }

   if (numberplus < numberminus) {
      return numberplus
   } else {
   return numberminus}
   }
```

When invoked, the function just returns '0'. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the position of 1 as starting point and loop up and (if necessary) down the array:

```js
const log = (arr, d) => console.log(`mimimal distance [${arr.join()}]: ${d}`);

const arr = [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2];
const arr2 = [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2];
const arr3 = [2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2];
const arr4 = [2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2];

log(arr, clostes(arr));
log(arr2, clostes(arr2));
log(arr3, clostes(arr3));
log(arr4, clostes(arr4));

function clostes(arr) {
  // determine position of 1
  const indxOf1 = arr.indexOf(1);
  
  // create array of distances
  const distances = [0, 0];
  
  // forward search
  for (let i = indxOf1; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (arr[i] === 2) {
      break;
    }
    distances[0] += arr[i] !== 2 ? 1 : 0;
  }
  
  // if 1 is @ position 0 backwards search
  // is not necessary and minimum equals the
  // already found maximum
  if (indxOf1 < 1) {
    distances[1] = distances[0];
    return Math.min.apply(null, distances);
  }
  
  // backwards search
  for (let i = indxOf1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (arr[i] === 2) {
      break;
    }
    distances[1] += arr[i] !== 2 ? 1 : 0;
  }
  
  return Math.min.apply(null, distances);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do the job. You could make the code shorter but I've tried to make it clear. Once we find `1`, start at that index and keep checking adjacent indices. We also do bounds checking to ensure we don't overflow either end.

```
function closest(arr) {
    const index = arr.findIndex(n => n === 1);
    const len = arr.length;

    let offset = 1;
    while (true) {
        const before = index - offset;
        const after = index + offset;
        const beforeBad = before < 0;
        const afterBad = after >= len;

        // It's necessary to check both, we could exceed the bounds on one side but not the other.
        if (beforeBad && afterBad) {
            break;
        }

        if ((!beforeBad && arr[before] === 2) || (!afterBad && arr[after] === 2)) {
            return offset;
        }
        ++offset;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `arr.findIndex(n => n === 1);` should just be `arr.indexOf(1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this using [entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

```
const arr = [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0 ,2];
const goal = arr.indexOf(1);
const indices = [];

// Find all the indices of 2 in the array
for (let x of arr.entries()) {
  if (x[1] === 2) indices.push(x[0]) ;
}

// Find the index that is closest to your goal
const nearestIndex = indices.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
}); // 5

console.log(Math.abs(goal - nearestIndex));  // 1
```

Comment: and...  `Math.abs(goal-answer)`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
Output = Input.map((cur,idx,arr)=>cur==2?Math.abs(idx-arr.indexOf(1)):Infinity).sort()[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could avoid `for` loops here in favor of a more functional style. The function `minDist` takes `m`, `n`, and `array` as arguments, and returns the minimum distance between the *first* occurrence of `m` and any occurrence of `n` in an array.

First, `map` is used to create an array with pairs for each element containing the distance to the target `m` element and the value of the current element. Then `filter` is used to keep only the pairs representing `n` elements. Then `sort` is used so that the pairs representing the closest elements are at the beginning of the array. Finally, the `[0]` pair of the sorted array represents the closest element, and the `[0]` element of this closest pair is the minimum distance.

```js
function minDist(m, n, array) {
    let index = array.indexOf(m);
    return array
        .map((x, i) => [Math.abs(i - index), x])
        .filter(p => p[1] === n)
        .sort()[0][0];
}

console.log(minDist(1, 2, [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2]));
console.log(minDist(1, 2, [2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2]));
```